# Instantiate Double Pointer Using NewC,

Tags: c++

In C,

```
sFoo** foo = (sFoo**)malloc(2 * sizeof(sFoo*));
```

what is equivalent of this code to C++ using new?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using C++, I recommend not using `new`.

Comment: @chris - your suggestion has left me rather curious. Why would you advise against it?

Comment: @enhzflep, [This](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1) is a good start on the topic. Pointers that own resources are not inherently exception safe, and cause messier code in that you have to write extra class members to deal with copying an object and extra cleanup code anywhere, and ensure that cleanup code is run from every possible branch of execution.

Comment: @enhzflep i think he meant using value types, not "use malloc instead of new in C++" which is what it sounded like

Comment: Ah, good point. I can see how my comment looks like it could advocate using `malloc` instead. That's the opposite of the intended direction.

Comment: @chris - Cheers, thanks for the response. :goes off to the link:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the equivalent code is

```
sFoo** foo = new sFoo*[2];
```

u are allocating an array of 2 `sFoo*`.

also as a note for ur C code, it is not recommended to cast from `void*` to another type because it is unnecessary and a mainenance hassle. in c++ it is necessary tho if u just run that code in a C++ compiler.